# 'OutofMemoryException' whilst data trasnfer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, arcgis-9.3, data-transfer

I have a process in which data is transferred from PGDB to SDE GDB, recently I have encountered error - 'OutofMemoryException' and the process stops. I have noticed this error while trying to transfer line features in bulk (process works fine with the same amount of data in point or polygon). 
Once this error is encountered, I am unable to open source PDGB, trying to open it gives an error - "Failed to connect to database. 
            An underlying database error occurred. 
            System Resources Exceeded." 
New session of ArcMap allows to open PGDB but data transfer will still not proceed.

The transfer happens here to a feature class inside a versioned feature class inside a feature dataset, which also has a geometric network in it.

Version used here is ArcGIS 9.3.1 SP2 (GDB is also upgraded) with SQL SERVER 2008R2.

Comment: You may find some things to try at http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=985&t=230220#844193 and http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/failed-to-connect-to-database-an-underlying/9f4d1fbd-b74a-4705-ac0c-8c59fdabd64e but trying the same workflow on a machine with more RAM may also be worthwhile anytime you receive an error that mentions being out of memory.